# Determine row and column index of input in table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on creating a javascript based spreadsheet application. Right now I can dynamically create the spreadsheet as a table with a supplied number of rows and columns and a text input in each cell as can be seen in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flYTr.jpg).

I'd like to have a generic event tied to all of the inputs in the table in which I am able to determine the row index and column index of the input that fired the event. Something like this:

```
$('.spreadsheet-cell').click(function () {
     var rowIndex = $(this).attr('rowIndex');
     var columnIndex = $(this).attr('columnIndex');
});
```

I originally tried implementing things by dynamically adding row and column index attributes to the html input element when I create it but when I add rows or columns after the original spreadsheet has been created things get messy trying to shift the value of these attributes around. I think I could make that method work if it came down to it but it seems messy and I'd prefer not to mess around so much with the DOM when I figure that there is probably some way using jQuery to determine the relative index of the parent `<td>` and `<tr>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use jQuery [`.index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).  Within your function:

```
var rowIndex = $("#table tr").index($(this).closest('tr'));
var colIndex = $("#table td").index(this);
```

Comment: @JesseCarter you may have more luck by more or less reversing the selector and `.index` arguments.  jQuery seems to support both, which is confusing as hell to me, the way I wrote it tends to work for my purposes consistently

Comment: I guess the table will have a header row followed by a bunch of data rows. If so, then you may run into issues with `index()` which, if you aren't careful, will give the header row as index 0. Fortunately, there will/should(?) be a `tbody` even if it doesn't explicitly appear in the HTML (personally, I would make it explicit). By getting the row index within the `.closest('tbody')`, you should be OK. Similarly, in calculating the row index, you may need to take measures to reject the initial cell, if that is a row heading.

Comment: @ExplosionPills Your implementation almost works flawlessly. It gets the rowIndex right on but its returning '1' for every columnIndex regardless of which input was selected. I tried changing that to:

var colIndex = jQuery("#spreadsheet-table td").index(jQuery(this).closest('td'));

But if I do that it starts returning the index of the td element relative to the entire page.

Comment: @JesseCarter can you give me some HTML and JS to work with, ideally on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Sure I will do my best, I've never used jsfiddle before but I know its a great tool so I'll try to recreate the problem

Comment: @ExplosionPills That wasn't as bad as I thought. Here is a jsFiddle demonstrating the problem
http://jsfiddle.net/xTasd/

Comment: Probably something like `var colIndex = $(this).closest("tr").find("td").index(this);`, or even `var colIndex = $(this).index();
`?

Comment: @JesseCarter this may be suboptimal, but I wasn't expecting the inputs.  It does make sense, though: http://jsfiddle.net/xTasd/1/

Comment: @ExplosionPills it seems to be working great! Thanks so much for all your help thats fantastic. Do you think it might be sub optimal in terms of performance?

Comment: @JesseCarter doubtful unless you have thousands of table cells; try not to use `jQuery()` on the same selector more than once.

Comment: For better efficiency, you can delegate to the table element - [http://jsfiddle.net/xTasd/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/xTasd/2/) (Note, I swapped row:col for col:row in the alert).

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot I agree with your other changes but why would using delegation be more efficient than binding directly?

Comment: It's for memory efficiency, not execution speed. One handler rather than many instances of the same handler .... as I understand it.

Comment: Sorry, that's wrong. One attachment of the handler rather than multiple attachments. It's the number of attachments that differs in this case, not the number of handlers. Probably doesn't make much difference either way.

Comment: Nice Beetroot thats awesome I'll definitely use that implementation as its the most concise by far. If you wanna post it as an answer I'll give you an upvote as well although Explosion Pills got here first so I'm gonna leave his marked as correct